# Store AESCipher object in mySQL

Tags: mysql, binary, aes

I'm encrypting some user data (no passwords) using Crypto.Cipher AES.

The return is a AESCipher of the form:

> b'o\xab\xdd\x19\xaat\xfcIAN\xd2\x00\xe9'

sometimes it produces spaces and non hex representations.

> b"N%?\x91\xe8'J\xc0\x10 p"
>
> b'QV8>K\xd8\xfa\x9a\x05%\xe8LJp\xd0gf'

When I try to insert these values into the SQL table created as:

```
data_encrypted VARBINARY(40)
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning: (1300, "Invalid utf8 character string: 'ABDD19'")
```

Seems like it's trimming the binary array, when I Query the inserted rows in the table, the row was effectively inserted but only the first bytes of the array, from b'o\xab\xdd\x19\xaat\xfcIAN\xd2\x00\xe9' it inserts only the 'o'.

Do I have to specify something else in the format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a _binary solved the warning 
self.cur.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO members VALUES(%s,_binary %s...

And I'm also formatting the array to be hex represented, it looks better in the MySQL table and the decryption still works ok binascii.b2a_hex

Comment: And I'm also formatting the array to be hex represented, it looks better in the mysql table and the decryption still works ok